# How to add an extra file into electron package

Tags: electron

I just started my adventure with electron and built an app which uses SQLite.

I use electron-vue and for sqlite I use sql.js package.

And everything is just fine when I compile my app using npm run dev.
The problem begins when I want to package the app. Then except the mac version the db.sqlite is not included into the app so of course, it does not work correctly.

How can I add the database file into a built app that I could then distribute to the client?

Answer (score 2):

I have found kind of solution: I added

`"extraFiles": [ 
"db.sqlite"
],`

to the `package.json` file so now the app works when I start it from ./build/linux-unpacked folder.

I called it kind of solution as it still doesn't work from packaged file. But I guess this can't be helped because of the way the one file package works.
Or maybe somebody knows the solution?